# Drawing a loading screen with percentage, when loading means Drawing a lot of things

Tags: c#, multithreading, xna

In my XNA game I need, at the beginning, to load some image and then Draw a lot of images to be used later in the game. I wanted to draw a loader that shows the progress, but I faced the problem that I can't draw while another spritebatch is already drawing.

It is something like:

I trait this as a thread:

```
public void DrawCache
{
   progress = 0; // I can get this variable from outside
   foreach (SpriteToBeCached in AllSprites)
   {
      graphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(SpriteToBeCached.MyCachedTexture);
      spriteBatch.Begin();
      spriteBatch.Draw( ... );
      spriteBatch.End();
      graphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
      ++progress;
   }
}
```

The Update menu state:

```
   ...
   if (!loading)
   { 
       var loading_thread = new Thread(DrawCache);
       loading = false;
   }
   ...
```

The Draw menu state:

```
   ...
   GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);
   spriteBatch.Begin();
   spriteBatch.DrawString(font, progress, position, Color.White);
   spriteBatch.End();
   ...
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: check this article: http://jakepoz.com/jake_poznanski__background_load_xna.html

Comment: It is very interesting, what about Unloading/Disposing contents?

Comment: i guess... loop over assets, and unload each of them depend on type. didn't tried this example, i had this page in bookmarks but never implemented.